# CloudKit: can't discover identities

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Pretty new to CloudKit. Trying to get all the contacts who are using my app. According to the docs and the tutorials out there I'm calling this:

```
discoverAllIdentities(completionHandler:)
```

The issue is that only my user (the one who is logged in on the device where the app is running) is returned. So I did some digging and noticed that if I call this one:

```
discoverUserIdentity(withPhoneNumber:completionHandler:)
```

and I use phone number directly the user is returned.

So after more investigation, I figured that the reason I do not get those users is that in my Contacts those users do not have their iCloud email stored. So once I add the email, they are returned by `discoverAllIdentities(completionHandler:)`. So it appears the default implementation of that method is tied to iCloud emails for the discovery instead of phone number.

Is it possible to use phone number for `discoverAllIdentities(completionHandler:)`? Since, I don't think that as you add a new contact you would record anything but just phone number, so you will be missing to discover all those users.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.